# android tablerow edit gestures

Tags: android, tablerow, android-tablelayout, android-gesture

enter code hereIn my android application , there is a populated tableview with favorite products. There is a delete functionality to delete products from the list. How can i show this to user that he can delete products? like in ios there is a method called commiteditingstyle.
What are the options in pure android way to edit tablerows

- longclicklistener and show a delete button on table row
- show a checkbox on edit button

any other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's really just up to your imagination. I think typical android UI would just use the flick to remove, but some like the longpress or a button, some use an "Edit List" option which adds a checkbox next to each item on the list and then gives the user an option to delete selected items(best for managing large list or batch quantities).

Hope that helps! Good Luck!